# In the approximation of binomial distribution by a normal distribution, why should the range between which the area is found increase by one?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, approximation, binomial-distribution

That is, why is the following true?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $a\le X\lt b$ or $a\le X\le b$?

Comment: I mean the former a≤X<b.

Comment: Then it would be area from $a-1/2$ to $b-1/2$.

Comment: Oh why? Since the method is excerpted from a textbook Fundamental of Biostatistics:

Comment: (I am assuming $a$ and $b$ are integers.) Because $b$ is excluded.  As to textbook, they can have typos. If $\le b$ was meant, it would be to $b+1/2$.

Comment: I am getting more confused. Why is this so?

Comment: I have written out a brief answer.  The real story is more complicated, sometimes applying the continuity correction leads to less accurate answers.  But mostly the continuity correction improves the fit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. That is very succinct.

Comment: If the book is being quoted correctly, it is simply wrong.

Comment: This site uses MathJax formatting. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Another way to see that the book is wrong: for the special case $a=b$, $Pr(a \le X \lt b)$ would reduce to $Pr(a \le X \lt a)$ which must be zero because the event is impossible -with probability _not_ equal to $Pr(X=a)$-, according to the area under the normal curve from $a-\frac{1}{2}$ to $a-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the continuity correction factor. Recall that the binomial distribution is discrete. If you imagine plotting a histogram of a particular binomial distribution, then fitting a normal curve to it, you will see that it is not a perfect match.

To compensate for this, in the case that you seek $$P(a\leq X<b)$$
you will have to subtract $.5$ to $a$ to 'capture' $a$ so that you will have $a\leq X$ and subtract $.5$ from $b$ to 'avoid' $b$ so that you will have $X<b$.

Here is an image I found [here](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~campbell/stat/prob9.html).

[image]

Let's say I want $P(3\leq X< 8)$. Notice that I will have to subtract $.5$ from $3$ to 'capture' (the approximation) $3\leq X$ and subtract $.5$ from $8$ to avoid $8$ (in the approximation to) $X<8$.
If I add $.5$ to $8$, then I am capturing $8$ and so I will have $X\leq 8$, which is ***not*** what I want.

---

Similarly, let's consider $P(8\leq X)$; again notice that to capture $8$, I have to subtract $.5$ from $8$ so that I will get an approximation to $P(8\leq X)$. This is the purple shaded region.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ have binomial distribution, and let $W$ be the usual approximating normal. Let $k$ be an integer.

The continuity correction is based on the belief, partly grounded in fact, that 
$$\Pr(X=k)\approx \Pr(k-1/2\lt W\lt k+1/2),\tag{1}$$
and that other possible approximations, such as $\Pr(k-1\lt W\lt k)$, are not as good.

Summing up (1) from $a$ to $b-1$, we get
$$\Pr(a\le X\lt b)\approx W(b-1/2)-W(a-1/2).$$